# Platform independent file monitoring system for C?

Tags: monitoring, c

I'm looking for an OS independent library to detect when files in a directory are added, modified, or deleted. I know there are OS specific way so to do this (inotify for Linux, fsevents for mac, etc), but is there a platform independent library the works specifically in c? I know there is qfile system watcher, but that is implemented in c++.